# Interactive visualization of a graph in python

Tags: python, graphics, graph, networkx, graph-visualization

I have a program written in python using the module ***[networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html)*** to create a dynamic graph. It is a planer graph where the vertices remain constant but the edges change. Now I'm looking for a library that allows me to do two things, in a fast and quick manner preferably:

1. Drawing the vertices as the lattice points inside a rectangle, i.e.

   [image: Lattice]
2. Being able to select edges and vertices to change their color, position, weights, etc. as shown in the picture.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modest graph sizes, any good python graphics library should provide sufficient primitives to address this issue. For example, either [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) or [PyGame](http://pygame.org/news.html) would be suitable.